# Remove / update all lists from a list that meet a certain criterion

Tags: prolog

I want to remove / update all lists from a list that meet a certain criterion.

Example (what I want to do):

List: `[ [a,b,c], [x,y,z] [a,b], [b,a,c], [b] ]`

Criterion: does not contain a.
Result: `[[x,y,z], [b]].`

What I've tried:

```
criterion(A, L, Small_List):- 
        member(Small_list,L), member(A,Small_list).
remove_lists(A,L,L1):-  
        criterion(A,L, Small_List), select(Small_List,L,Q), remove_lists(A, Q, L1).
```

When I try `trace, remove_lists(a, [ [a,b,c], [x,y,z] [a,b], [b,a,c], [b] ], L1).` and I follow the GUI debugger, I see the corresponding lists are removed. However, the result is always False, although I was expecting `L1 = [[x,y,z], [b]].`

What did I do wrong? How can I modify the lists selected by a given criterion? For example, let's say I want to keep the lists containing 'a', but I want to remove 'a' from all lists, like that:
Input = `[ [a,b,c], [x,y,z], [a,b], [b,a,c], [b] ]`, Output = `[ [b,c], [x,y,z], [b], [b,c], [b] ]`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple than you would expect.

```
remove_list(a,[],[]).
remove_list(a,[H|T],SmallList):- member(a,H) , remove_list(a,T,SmallList).
remove_list(a,[H|T],[H|SmallList]):- \+member(a,H) , remove_list(a,T,SmallList).
```

**OUTPUT**

```
?-remove_list(a,[ [a,b,c], [x,y,z], [a,b], [b,a,c], [b] ],Z).
  Z= [[x, y, z], [b]]
```

You make the code flexible like giving the criterion as input also.

```
remove_list(,[],[]).
remove_list(X,[H|T],SmallList):- member(X,H) , remove_list(X,T,SmallList).
remove_list(X,[H|T],[H|SmallList]):- \+member(X,H) , remove_list(X,T,SmallList).
```

**OUTPUT**

```
?-remove_list(b,[ [a,b,c], [x,y,z], [a,b], [b,a,c], [b] ],Z).
  Z = [[x, y, z]]

?-remove_list(x,[ [a,b,c], [x,y,z], [a,b], [b,a,c], [b] ],Z).
  Z = [[a, b, c], [a, b], [b, a, c], [b]]
```

Hope this helped you.